# Universal prüfer-group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} := \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} | \exists m \in \mathbb{N}: z^m = 1 \rbrace$. It is easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} = \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$. Now I want to show that for every subgroup $U \leq \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ we get
\begin{equation}
U = \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}(U \cap \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}).
\end{equation}
Since $U \leq \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ we have to show
\begin{equation}
U \cap \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}} = \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}U_p.
\end{equation}
Edit: Let $U \leq \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ and $z \in U \cap \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ where
\begin{equation}
\bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}} = \lbrace (z_p)_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \in \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}} : z_p \neq 0 \mbox{ for finite many } p \in \mathbb{P} \rbrace.
\end{equation}
Let $h = (h_p)_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \in U$. I want to show that $h = (h_p)_{p \in \mathbb{P}}$ for $h_p \neq 0$ for finitely many $p$ and $h_p \in U_p \leq \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ for every $p \in \mathbb{P}$ where $h_p \neq 0$. I know that when one writes $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} = \bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ then there exists a Isomorphism $\varphi : \bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ such that $(z_p)_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \mapsto \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}}z_p$. Therefore $\varphi((h_p)_p) = \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}}h_p$. Now I cannot see how $h_p \in U_p$. My guess would be: $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ hence if we look at each component and take the componentwise multiplication each of the components must be contained in a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ for all $p \in \mathbb{P}$ under the product in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ hence $\subseteq$. Now I don't understand what $U \cap \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ really means and if that is really the same as the p component $U_p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ is not the internal direct product of the Prufer groups; the direct product contains elements of infinite order (unless you are using "internal direct product" to mean "internal **restricted** direct product).

Comment: With internal direct product I mean: A group $G$ is the internal direct product of two subgroups $A,B \leq G$ iff $A,B \triangleleft G$ and $AB = G$ and $A \cap B = \lbrace e \rbrace$.

Comment: We didn't define the internal direct product of infinite many groups, but it is probably the internal restricted direct product.

Comment: Well, then just use the direct sum symbol. They mean exactly the same thing. There's a reason we don't define "internal direct product" for infinitely many subgroups... it doesn't give what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in\mathbb{Z}_{{\infty}}$. What are its $p$-components?

If $g$ has order $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$, with $p_1\lt\cdots\lt p_r$, $\alpha_i\gt 0$, let $n_i=n/p_i^{\alpha_i}$. Then $g^{n_i}$ has order $p_i^{\alpha_i}$. Moreover, since $\gcd(n_1,\ldots,n_r)=1$, there exist integers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r$ such that
$$\alpha_1n_1+\cdots + \alpha_rn_r = 1.$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
g &= g^1\\
& = g^{\alpha_1n_1+\cdots + \alpha_rn_r}\\
&= (g^{n_1})^{\alpha_1}\cdots (g^{n_r})^{\alpha_r}.
\end{align}$$
This is then the expression of $g$ as $(g_p)\in\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$.

Now, given $u\in U$, proceeding as above, we see that the $p$-components of $u$ are powers of $u$, and hence lie in $U\cap \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$. This shows that $U$ is contained in $\oplus U_p$.